# Как переименовать репозиторий?

Tags: github

Можно ли переименовать репозиторий в который уже загружены данные?
Если да то как?

Под репозиторием я понимаю когда заходишь в свой аккаунт и там вкладки:

```
Overview    Repositories 1  Stars 1 Followers 0 Following 0
```

И когда нажимаешь на `Repositories` там список репозиториев, который через `$ git init` инициализируем на локальной машине.

Comment: Что именно вы хотите переименовать? Локальный репозиторий или remote?

Comment: каталог, в котором располагается рабочая копия файлов, вполне можно переименовать. это же просто каталог.

Comment: @Uladzimir Palekh дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @Павел, аккаунт где? GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, смешная четвёртая опция?

Comment: Ну, по идее, [берёте и переименовываете](http://i.imgur.com/K1EcfQa.png). Но это гитхаб. Не путайте гит и гитхаб.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh там много ещё разных опций, gogs например очень даже неплох.

Comment: Павел, вы путаете git и, вероятно, GitHub.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Откройте нужный принадлежащий вам репозиторий.
2. Откройте таб Settings:

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Там введите новое имя репозитория и нажмите <kbd>Rename</kbd>.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. В соответствующем локальном репозитории выполните следующую команду, чтобы переключить его на новый адрес удалённого:

   - Если используете соединение по протоколу HTTPS (когда вводите логин и пароль при `git pull`, `git push`):

     ```
       git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<ваш-логин>/<новое-имя-репозитория>.git
     ```
   - Если используете соединение по протоколу SSH (когда создали специальный ключ и добавили его на гитхаб, а пароль никогда не вводите):

     ```
       git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<ваш-логин>/<новое-имя-репозитория>.git
     ```

Comment: Вместо `git remote orgin set-url https://github.com/<ваш-логин>/<новое-имя-репозитория>.git`  нужно `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<ваш-логин>/<новое-имя-репозитория>.git`

Comment: @IkarDedalovich точно, вы правы.